# How to split an XML file using XSLT 2.0 in Python

Tags: python, xslt-2.0

I have an XML file which I want to split into multiple XML by processing it through xslt 2.0 file. How do I do it? I am currently using Python 2.7.6.  I have tried to use the following code:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse(xml_filename)
xslt = ET.parse(xsl_filename)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

But this returns None.

**Example XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <name>dataset containing bounding box labels on images</name>
    <comment>created by BBTag</comment>
    <tags>
        <tag name="Perimeter-SVT" color="#f9e99c"/>
        <tag name="Perimeter-Vivon" color="#032585"/>
        <tag name="ScoreBoard-Vivon" color="#bf5786"/>
        <tag name="Perimeter-StarSports" color="#12dadd"/>
    </tags>
    <images>
        <image file="/var/www/html/tamsports.com/resources/videos/STAR_SPORTS_2_20170812/STAR_SPORTS_2_20170812-0011.jpg">
            <box top="505" left="327" width="56" height="29">
                <label>ScoreBoard-Vivon</label>
            </box>
            <box top="218" left="387" width="67" height="24">
                <label>Perimeter-SVT</label>
            </box>
        </image>
        <image file="/var/www/html/tamsports.com/resources/videos/STAR_SPORTS_2_20170812/STAR_SPORTS_2_20170812-0005.jpg">
            <box top="254" left="159" width="64" height="23">
                <label>Perimeter-Vivon</label>
            </box>
            <box top="255" left="225" width="61" height="20">
                <label>Perimeter-Vivon</label>
            </box>
            <box top="254" left="285" width="63" height="23">
                <label>Perimeter-Vivon</label>
            </box>
            <box top="253" left="357" width="58" height="24">
                <label>Perimeter-Vivon</label>
            </box>
            <box top="254" left="424" width="56" height="25">
                <label>Perimeter-Vivon</label>
            </box>
            <box top="256" left="484" width="65" height="23">
                <label>Perimeter-Vivon</label>
            </box>
            <box top="507" left="326" width="58" height="26">
                <label>ScoreBoard-Vivon</label>
            </box>
        </image>
        <image file="/var/www/html/tamsports.com/resources/videos/STAR_SPORTS_2_20170812/STAR_SPORTS_2_20170812-0009.jpg">
            <box top="249" left="400" width="59" height="29">
                <label>Perimeter-StarSports</label>
            </box>
        </image>
    </images>
</dataset>
```

**XSLT 2.0 File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template match="//dataset/tags">
      <xsl:for-each select="./tag">
            <xsl:variable name="tagName" select="@name" />

                <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$tagName}.xml">
                    <dataset>    
                        <xsl:copy-of select="/dataset/name"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="/dataset/comment"/>
                        <tags>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="/dataset/tags/tag[./@name = $tagName]"/>
                        </tags>
                        <images>
                        <xsl:for-each select="/dataset/images/image[./box/label/text() = $tagName]">
                            <image> 
                                <xsl:copy-of select="./@file"/>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="./box[./label[./text() = $tagName]]"/>
                            </image>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        </images>
                    </dataset>
                </xsl:result-document>                              
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is no XSLT 2 support at all in lxml/libxslt used by the Python modules. You need an XSLT 2 processor like Saxon 9, XmlPrime, Altova to use XSLT 2's `xsl:result-document`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python uses libxslt which supports the EXSLT `exsl:document` http://exslt.org/exsl/index.html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:template match="dataset/tags">
    <xsl:for-each select="tag">
      <xsl:variable name="tagName" select="@name" />

      <exsl:document method="xml" href="{$tagName}.xml">
        <dataset>
          <xsl:copy-of select="/dataset/name"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="/dataset/comment"/>
          <tags>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/dataset/tags/tag[@name = $tagName]"/>
          </tags>
          <images>
            <xsl:for-each select="/dataset/images/image[box/label = $tagName]">
              <image>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@file"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="box[label = $tagName]"/>
              </image>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </images>
        </dataset>
      </exsl:document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Many thanks...this works....Indeed i visited the exsl:document page....as I am a novice myself, couldn't make head or tail of it. Thank you.

Comment: For the sake of completion and to make this novice proof, I would like to add, I used the same code given above in my question to parse the xml files.  You may have to wait for a few seconds to a longer duration for the xmls to be created, depending on the size of your input xml.